# I want to iterate a range of years using for loop in django

Tags: python, django

I want to display a set range of years using for loop with some start year to the current year and then after each passing year, the current year will be that particular year.

**Example:** start year is 2010
the current year is 2020
It will display from the year '2010' to '2020'
So when 2021 comes the range will display from '2010' to '2021'

my code is:

```
import datetime

def daterange(start, end, step=datetime.timedelta(1)):
    current_year = start
    while current_year < end:
        yield curr
        curr += step
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
from datetime import date

def datefunc(start):
    return [i for i in range(start, date.today().year + 1)]
```

then run:

```
datefunc(2010)
```

your output would be:

```
[2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only care about the current year of all the `date` object then you can get it from `datetime.date.today().year` and use it.

```
import datetime

def daterange(start, end, step=1):
    current_year = start
    while current_year <= end:
        yield current_year
        current_year += step

# Replace 2010 by some starting point you want maybe dynamically.
for year in daterange(2010, datetime.date.today().year):
    print(year)
```